# Unable to download fie with rnFetchBlob in react native android app

Tags: android, reactjs, native

The pdf file gets downloaded when I am running code locally with localhost. However, when the code gets deployed in elastic beanstalk I am unable to download file. The code looks like below:

I am getting the below error:

**[Error: Download manager failed to download from ... . Status Code = 16]**

````
    let token = await Secure.get('auth');
    const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob;
    let DownloadDir = fs.dirs.DownloadDir;
    console.log(DownloadDir + "/" + new Date().getTime() + ".pdf")
    let options = {
        fileCache : true,
        addAndroidDownloads: {
            useDownloadManager: true,
            notification: true,
            mime: 'application/pdf',
            title: "Test Invoice", 
            path: DownloadDir + "/" + new Date().getTime() + ".pdf", 
            description: 'Downloading file.',
            mediaScannable: true
        }
    }
    config(options)
        .fetch('GET', urls.ORDER_URL + '/order/download?orderId=' + orderId, { Authorization: token, 'Cache-Control': 'no-store' })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
        })
        .catch((err) => { console.log('error is..:', err) }) 
}```
````